# PHP Friendly Urls for my script

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect, url-rewriting, cmsmadesimple

I have a site which I have converted to use cms made simple. It works perfectly and I have the friendly urls working fine too. My issue is with a little script I wrote myself and how best to integrate it. The script is a gallery script, it reads a directory and outputs a formatted gallery in html. I was planning on making it a user defined tag in cms made simple but I hit a small snag.

The gallery script needs to be able to read in two values from the url groupId and showpage.

If I am using freindly urls then the cms and use the tag I hit a snag as the cms tries to find an actual page at "www.mysite.com/gallery/mygroup/2" and then throws a 404.

basically I need

```
http://www.mysite.com/gallery/photogroup/2
```

rewritten to

```
http://www.mysite.com/gallery.php?groupId=photogroup&showpage=2
```

**UPDATE**
Follwoing Yuri's advice I added his rule to the htaccess. But I have hit another snag.
So for instance if we go to 
`http://www.mysite.com/gallery/photogroup/2`
then Yuri's rule should take effect. But that path is also a correct physical directory on my site coincidentally. Is there a way to have the rewrite rule take effect instead of bringing me to a white screen browsing the files in the directory or to the forbidden screen if I have indexes turned off which I do.

Below is my htaccess

```
php_flag magic_quotes_gpc Off

RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1

RewriteRule ^gallery/(\w+)/(\d+)$ gallery.php?groupId=$1&showpage=$2 [QSA,L]
```

Comment: Sorry, but it is unclear what specific problem do you have. Could you simply explain exactly what url do you want to see and where should it redirect. Some example?

Comment: my apologies, I reread it and it really was not clear in my question. Thanks for the reply, I have now updated it and provided and example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, did you try to write in `.htaccess` something like this?

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond ${REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond ${REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^gallery/(\w+)/(\d+)$ gallery.php?groupId=$1&showpage=$2 [QSA,L]
```

Comment: ya I tried that exact rule already but it does not do anything. The server just brings me to the actual directory as gallery/groupId is an actual physical directory too although the public user would not be aware of this. its exactly what I am after if I could just get it to work. thanks for the help. I have one rewrite rule above this in the htaccess but that should not be interfering with it should it.

Comment: Are you really sure mod_rewrite is enabled in your Apache config?
Also in some cases you will need to specify `RewriteBase /` (/ - replace to the actual path of your document root it differs from Apache's config). Don't know if it helps, but you should always check this in case you are working with `.htaccess`

Comment: May be try to remove RewriteConds (which actually do check if there is some real file or directory) and add some options before RewriteEngine.

    `Options +FollowSymlinks -Indexes -MultiViews`

Answer (score 0):

sounds like a "module" to me. Maybe this [Make your module use clean URLs](http://wiki.cmsmadesimple.org/index.php/User_Handbook/Developers_Guide/Creating_Modules#Make_your_module_use_clean_URLs)